# menu link opens module under menu module - joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, module, menuitem

maybe it an easy solution for someone..I would like how can I set up an item in menu (positioned on right side of template), that when I click it, it opens/shows a module (news blog) under that menu(item) (in the same right position). Similar to click accordion just that menu item is in a menu module and a news blog is another module.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla you can assign modules to specific menu items. THat means the module will appear when you click that item.  You can assign a module to one page, all pages, specific pages you click or "all except" a list you select.  Other than that I'm not sure what the question is, but I will say it's not a programming question.

Comment: true, the module will appear on click but the page (that module is assigne to show at) will be blank.

Comment: Why would the page be blank?

Comment: What would be the content of the page then if its not blank?

Comment: WHatever was linked to in the menu.

Comment: so article or component..I think modules cant be (directly) linked in menu (of course it can be through article which has loadposition inside but thats not what Im looking for).

Comment: No articles cannot be linked directly only components can.

Answer (score 0):

In joomla module can also show in article,

You can create a article and link those article to specific menu.

And those article called a  module like {loadmodule module_name}.

Also with module position like this {loadposition position_name}.

Comment: but this will open module in article when I click menu item. When I click menu item I only want module to appear below that menu (both menu and module as positioned on right side/column of template). Main content of the page should stay the same (no new article load)